# Allowing only certain values though a strong parameter in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a field **otp_set_up**, which in the **company_user** model is allowed to be "true" or "false".

There is a use case where a sys admin user can reset this field to "false".

While the field can be set to "true" through code, NO user can set it to "true" via a form edit etc.

I haven't added to it the validation in the model since it can be "true" or "false".

I have the following code in a params method specific to an update in the controller before the params.require .permit bit:

```
if curr_company_user.is_sys_admin? && curr_company_user.can_crud_company_users? && params[:id].to_i != curr_company_user.id

  params[:company_user] = params[:company_user].except(:otp_set_up) if params[:company_user][:otp_set_up] == true
  params.require(:company_user).permit(:otp_setup, etc. etc....

elsif etc. etc...
```

This works. A Sys admin user can not set otp_set_up to "true".

My question is:

Is this the best and correct way to do this in Rails? It seems a bit hacky to me, going through the params hash and removing a bit.

Is there a better / cleaner way?

Comment: Do you set the value to "true" through code in the view or controller or just the model?

Comment: That actually isn't implemented yet! but should be set to "true" in a otp_setup controller create method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`delete_if` cleans it up. Still a bit hacky, but slightly less so : )

```
params.require(:company_user).permit(:otp_setup).delete_if do |key, val|
  key == 'otp_setup' && val == true
end
```

This leaves the original `params` object intact.

There isn't a built in way to do this. It looks like there used to be but no more https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/167

`delete_if` is defined on `Hash` in the core library, so it is probably the best way to do it in Ruby and by extension in Rails in the absence of a built in method.

## Update

I thought it was an interesting idea, so I wrote a small gem called [allowable](https://github.com/msimonborg/allowable) for this type of use case. It will add a few methods to `Hash` and `ActionController::Parameters`: `#allow`, `#allow!`, `#forbid` and `#forbid!`

You would use it like this

```
params.require(:company_user).permit(:otp_setup).forbid(otp_setup: [true])

# or

params.require(:company_user).permit(:otp_setup).allow(otp_setup: [false])
```

You can specify a single value or an array of values, and it doesn't mutate the original `params` object

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to go with your delete_if suggestion. Nice work on the gem, unfortunately I can't use it in work for the production system (not allowed). Pity they didn't take your feature proposal onboard for ActionController::Parameters. That seems to me where it belongs in cases like this.

Comment: @Iain Sure no problem. Feel free to look at the actual implementation i used in the gem which is faster than #delete_if

Comment: As in "delete(key)" in the loop instead of the "delete_if" before the def of the loop?

Comment: I now need to strip out values from a number of params, so I'm pasting the code for multiple ones. Note the dots at the end of lines to chain together. It took me a while to figure out since I'm newish to Rails.

 `params.require(:user).permit(:failed_login_count, :active, :otp_setup, :otherthings).`

`delete_if do |key, val| key == 'failed_login_count' && val.to_i != 0`

`end.`

`delete_if do |key, val| key == 'active' && val == 'false'`
`end.`
`delete_if do |key, val| key == 'otp_setup' && val == 'true'`
`end`

Comment: This is a nice gem, keeps the ugly delete_if formatting out of the controller

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that you set it in the params only if the user is an admin and not otherwise. I think this is a better way.

In the model, do something like this:

```
if user.role == 'admin'
  attr_accessor #All the params
else
  attr_accessor #All the other params except the one you want to 
  exclude
```

Comment: That actually is done already in my code. I just didn't have it in the original question. I have added it now to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: In the model when you're setting the strong params. That's when you set the params for otp_set_up.

Comment: They should be set in the controller surely? That's where they are, but I searched for a way to only allow certain values in, but couldn't find a solution. e.g. something like

params.require(:company_user).permit(:otp_setup => false

and many different variants but nothing worked.

Comment: The thing is, I only want sys admin to be able to set otp_set_up to "false". That's why I currently strip out a "true" value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend messing around with the `params` object in this case. I think it's best to leave that untouched for the most part to preserve what was actually requested. That way you're not left scratching your head if you need that value again somewhere downstream.

Another approach is to build the list of attributes to accept before passing into `permit`.

```
# Attributes that everyone can modify.
attrs = [:attrs, :everyone, :can, :modify]

# Then "whitelist" other attributes based on your permission logic.
if curr_company_user.is_sys_admin? && curr_company_user.can_crud_company_users? && params[:id].to_i != curr_company_user.id
  attrs << :otp_set_up unless params[:company_user][:otp_set_up] == true
elsif something_else?
  # Modify what can be permitted for this case.
  # etc...
end

params.require(:company_user).permit(*attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I prefer the delete_if suggestion in another answer. Seems a bit tidier, but both your suggestions of not modifying the params object are the way to go!

Comment: @Iain No problem. I'd imagine that there are situations where `delete_if` would be less tidy. (Also, I always prefer a whitelisting approach than a blacklisting.) I'm assuming that others out there may have the same preference as me, so I'll leave my answer up as an alternative. Glad you found the best solution for your specific problem though.